# Phone wont boot

Tags: charging, boot

Yesterday I got an Acer Liquid Z410. After installing some apps and checking out the phone, I charged my phone fully. Then I was trying to acces my phone again but it was off. So I tried to access it by turning it on, but it wouldn't start. I even tried the power button + volume up button and power button + volume down. The phone does charge and I kept it on the charger for a full night. I cant get in recovery mode. I dont have much more information except for that I cant seem to find the solution anywhere. Not the manual, nowhere.What is going wrong and what should I do? I dont know my android version but I do know I have Android.

Comment: If it has a removable battery: did you try taking that out for a couple of minutes, and re-insert it? If the battery is not replaceable, there's usually some "reset hole" you could stick a needle in for a few seconds to reset it, with a similar effect.

Comment: @Izzy Yes I tried that

Comment: If it doesn't switch on at all, I'm afraid it's a case for being turned in to service. Might well be a hardware issue (e.g. broken power button or the like).

Comment: @Izzy Yup I did that. I'm getting a new one. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) – especially if you get some feedback from service on what the culprit was. Might turn out helpful to others :)

Comment: Anytime – and thanks for posting your solution as answer (+1 from me for that) :) Enjoy your new device!

Answer (score 1):

I went to the store and it had to do something with the hardware. I am getting a new phone and all is settled. Al though the store said they've never seen or hear about it happen before.